# authentication require to perform file operation - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, 22.04, authentication

I am new to Ubuntu and learning it from many days.
I have used 2 hard drives in my system (sda for data, sdb for Ubuntu os) . One for Ubuntu OS & other for data. Problem I am facing is the authentication pop-up every time I want to access any of partition from sda.
I am also unable to move files from one drive to other.
I am solo user of my system & not using/sharing it with anyone else or network
I am also facing `authentication required to run gvfsd-admin daemon`. I want to remove that pop-up because it appear every time when I restart and try to access any of partition
[authentication required gvfsd-admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTKna.png)
[image]

Comment: Welcome. The screenshot was unnecessary, we all know what it looks like ;) and yes, it's a problem with permissions probably due to the way it was formatted. Do you have data there already? If not just format it again with Disks.

Comment: HI, thank you for suggestion. But I have lot of data that is not easily possible to move. Is their any way where I stop that pop-up or any workout where I assign the authentication permanently? I dont want it every time. Which format for partition I need to use to get ride of that pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue with PolicyKit (polkit) aka polkit-1 Linux security, but not a problem.
You should create local policy exclude file for that entity.
The entity name you can obtain from `/var/log/auth.log`
Then create file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/46-allow-udisks2.pkla`
The "udisks2" part of filename is free to modify.
Content of file should be almost similar to:
[polkit for color profile promt](https://devanswers.co/how-to-fix-authentication-is-required-to-create-a-color-profile-managed-device-on-ubuntu-20-04-20-10/)
Just change to your obtained entity "Action=...;"
Last step:
`sudo systemctl restart polkit`
For further details you may look at manual policykit(8):
`man polkit`

Hope this help.